# Error flagging email message Java

Tags: java, email

Upon calling the following I code snipit:

```
Message message_in  = null;
inbox instanceof IMAPFolder
IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder)inbox;
f.idle();
System.out.println("IDLE done");                                              
message_in = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
message_in.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
inbox.expunge();
```

I receive the error message:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: A9 NO Command received in Invalid state.;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A9 NO Command received in Invalid state.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.setFlags(IMAPMessage.java:905)
    at javax.mail.Message.setFlag(Message.java:578)
    at com.name.vmmonitor.main.VMMonitor.startPolling(VMMonitor.java:160)
    at com.name.vmmonitor.main.VMMonitor.main(VMMonitor.java:283)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A9 NO Command received in Invalid state.
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:351)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.storeFlags(IMAPProtocol.java:1589)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.storeFlags(IMAPProtocol.java:1574)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.setFlags(IMAPMessage.java:901)
    ... 3 more
```

What is the issue?  I am able to call methods such as `message_in.getSubject()` but why not `message_in.setFlag()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "A9 NO Command received in Invalid state." means the IMAP folder (the account) is read-only.

Comment: Is an issue I need to address on the _server side_ (i.e. the mail server I am connecting to) or the _client side_ (i.e. a setting within my program)?

Comment: It could be either. It might be the way you're getting hold of the IMAPFolder or the way the server is set-up.